# Получение массива файлов с определенным расширением

Tags: node.js, файловая-система

Есть папка:

```
blocks
├── style.css
├── index.html
├── dir
└── script.js
```

Есть код который читает содержимое папки, а потом по идее должен удалять файлы расширения которых не `.htm` или `.html`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = {
  fileList: undefined,

};

fs.readdir('blocks/', function(err, files){
    console.log(files);
    console.log(files.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        console.log(files[i]);
        if (files[i].indexOf('.htm') === -1 || files[i].indexOf('.html') === -1){
            files.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

    data.fileList = files;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Однако почему то скрипт не хочет удалять последний файл из массива вне зависимости от его расширения.

В чем проблема?

p.s. если делать через `forEach` такая же ошибка.

Comment: `if (files[i].indexOf('.htm') !== -1 || files[i].indexOf('.html') !== -1)`

Comment: потому что, метод splice изменяет длину массива. Для того, что бы код работал, необходимо использовать другой массив

Comment: @Дмытрык добавьте ответом

Comment: @brachkoff,  я с телефона.  Для полноценного ответа нужно код писать. С телефона это неудобно. Может быть через пару недель;)

Answer (score -1):

данный код можно написать проще:

```
const skipExtentions = [".html"];

function readDir(dir, cb) {
  fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      cb(err, []);
    }

    cb(null, files.filter(f => {
      const ext = f.split(".").pop(); // get file ext
      return !skipExtentions.includes(ext);
    }))
  });
}

readDir("/blocks", (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  }

  data.fileList = files;
});
```

Comment: Мне нужно найти ошибку а не написать проще. Максимально простое решение я уже давно нашел.

Comment: Добрый день. Почему так грубо общаетесь? Если посмотрите на строки 9-10 в моём ответе, то увидите как отфильтровать файлы

Comment: Ничего грубого я не написал, я написал что ответ совсем не подходит.Подобные ответы это что то из раздела "вопрос про python ответ на c#". Посмотрите ответ пользователя Дмитрык, который является корректным.

Comment: Если посмотрите на строки 9-10 в моём ответе, то увидите как отфильтровать файлы

Comment: я бы предложил такой стиль общения: "ДОбрый день Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, он мне не совсем подходит (почему..). Удачи"

Comment: Я уже увидел как отфильтровать файлы в другом ответе, поэтому не вижу смысла разбирать код который значительно отличается от предложенного в вопросе.

Comment: для благодарности за хороший ответ на сайте есть увеличение репутации, а комментарии нужны для того чтобы решать проблему, а не говорить спасибо за странные ответы.

Comment: Такая культура у нас!